# CAML query not fetching desired results

Tags: 2013, caml-query, caml

I have a CAML query

```
<Query><Where><Or>"+
             "<Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='User'>" + User.Name + "</Value></Eq>"+
             "<Contains><FieldRef Name ='OtherUsers'/><Value Type = 'Text'> " + site.CurrentUser.Name + " </Value></Contains>"+
          "</Or></Where></Query>
```

This query is not fetching desired results. Especially the `<Contains>` part of the query. The `<Eq>` part works fine and it fetches results,  but the contains part is not. 
Contains part is checking a note field in SharePoint list

Comment: Are you storing display name of users in `OtherUsers` column?

Comment: 'OtherUsers' is single line or multiline text?

Comment: @Gaurravs Yes, I have their user id in it

Comment: @VishalMPatil It is a multiline note

Comment: Then change Value Type of 'OtherUsers' to 'Note' and then try.

Comment: @VishalMPatil it worked thanks
please post as answer

Comment: It should work with 'Text' as well

Comment: @Gaurravs you are right
Please check my updated answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. If '`OtherUsers`' is `multiline text` field then just change Value Type of `OtherUsers` to '`Note`'.

```
<Query><Where><Or>"+
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='User'>" + User.Name + "</Value></Eq>"+
"<Contains><FieldRef Name ='OtherUsers'/><Value Type = 'Note'> " + site.CurrentUser.Name + " </Value></Contains>"+
"</Or></Where></Query>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"<Where><Or>"+
      "<Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='User'>" + User.Name + "</Value></Eq>"+
      "<Contains><FieldRef Name='OtherUsers'/><Value Type='Text'> " + site.CurrentUser.LoginName + " </Value></Contains>"+
"</Or></Where>";
```

You need to use `site.CurrentUser.LoginName` instead of `site.CurrentUser.Name` to get LoginName of user. If you want to use Display name of user, then `site.CurrentUser.Name`

Check the various options and use based on what you are storing:

`site.CurrentUser.LoginName` : LoginName of user
`site.CurrentUser.Name` : Display Name of user
`site.CurrentUser.ID` : Integer ID of user

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue after some debugging and comments from @Gaurrav

The issue was the additional space that was there in the query!

**Old Query**

```
<Query><Where><Or>"+
             "<Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='User'>" + User.Name + "</Value></Eq>"+
             "<Contains><FieldRef Name ='OtherUsers'/><Value Type = 'Text'> " + site.CurrentUser.Name + " </Value></Contains>"+
          "</Or></Where></Query>
```

**Corrected Query**

```
<Query><Where><Or>"+
                 "<Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='User'>" + User.Name + "</Value></Eq>"+
                 "<Contains><FieldRef Name ='OtherUsers'/><Value Type = 'Text'>" + site.CurrentUser.Name + "</Value></Contains>"+
              "</Or></Where></Query>
```

Notice that the **Value** inside the **`<contains>`** query had additional spaces

**Lessons learnt:**

1. Don't add additional spaces for readability inside your CAML query.
2. Both Note and Text will work for multiple lines of text field

Comment: I would suggest not to keep additional space in `<Value Type = 'Text'>"` this as well . Refer my answer for same